# oracle trigger with group by

Tags: sql

Is it possible that command to be as Trigger?

```
INSERT INTO MAIN_ORDER(ORDER_ID, ORDER_PRICE ) 
SELECT ORDER_ID, SUM(TOTALCOST) 
FROM ORDER_DETAIL 
GROUP BY ORDER_ID;
```

Comment: A trigger on what table? Per row or not?

Comment: I have two tables: MAIN_ORDER and ORDER_DETAIL. I want after insert a row on ORDER_DETAIL, the order_id and the sum(totalcost) to be inserted to the MAIN_ORDER grouped by order_id

Comment: Refer to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374). What you likely need is `create trigger ... after insert for each row on order_detail as ...`. You would refer to the record being inserted as `:NEW`, that is, `:NEW.ORDER_ID`, etc.

Comment: a trigger ..after insert on ORDER_DETAIL  for each row ..is working, so I can insert data to MAIN_ORDER from ORDER_DETAIL . the Problem is when (after insert on order_detail) I want to get the sum of total cost and the order_id based on the order_id..and  to insert them to the MAIN_ORDER.